# How to merge rows inside a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, concatenation

```
         Reg No. |    Session | Course No. = Name Credit = Semester = |   CSE133 3.00 1st Semester |    CSE134 2.00 1st Semester | CSE143 3.00 1st Semester | CSE144 1.00 1st Semester
407 | 2017331108 |  2017-2018 | ZESHAN AHMED NABIN | 0.00 F           | 4.00 A+ |   4.00 A+ | 3.00 B
408 | 2017331108 |  2017-2018 | ZESHAN AHMED NABIN | NaN              | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
409 | 2017331108 |  2017-2018 | ZESHAN AHMED NABIN | 2.25 C           | NaN     |         | NaN
410 | 2017331108 |  2017-2018 | ZESHAN AHMED NABIN | NaN              | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
411 | 2017331109 |  2017-2018 | MD. ZAHIDUL AKRAM RATUL | 3.75 A |  3.75 A | 2.50 C+ | 3.75 A
412 | 2017331109 |  2017-2018 | MD. ZAHIDUL AKRAM RATUL | NaN    | NaN     | NaN     |  NaN
413 | 2017331109 |  2017-2018 | MD. ZAHIDUL AKRAM RATUL |        | NaN     |         | NaN
414 | 2017331109 |  2017-2018 | MD. ZAHIDUL AKRAM RATUL | NaN    | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
```

I want to merge this dataframe so that the 4 rows gets merged with the highest value from each of the columns
and there are 400 more similar inputs like this where each four of them has the same session, name.

**The output I want:**

```
         Reg No. |    Session | Course No. = Name Credit = Semester = |   CSE133 3.00 1st Semester |    CSE134 2.00 1st Semester | CSE143 3.00 1st Semester | CSE144 1.00 1st Semester
407 | 2017331108 |  2017-2018 | ZESHAN AHMED NABIN | 2.25 C           | 4.00 A+   | 4.00  A+ | 3.00 B
411 | 2017331109 |  2017-2018 | MD. ZAHIDUL AKRAM RATUL | 3.75 A |  3.75 A | 2.50 C+ | 3.75 A
```

The blank space in row 409 indicates empty string("").
I don't know what code to write to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want.

```
df.fillna('').groupby([
    'Session',
    'Course No. = Name Credit = Semester ='
], as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: It gives the following error.
'''ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 74, placement implies 50'''

Comment: Does it work on the segment of the dataframe that you pasted in your example? Also, are you running exactly the code I posted? I think that error usually shows up during assignment, which isn't happening in my answer.

Comment: I posted your example input into a text file and did this `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = '\s*\|\s*', header=0)

df.fillna('').groupby([
    'Session',
    'Course No. = Name Credit = Semester ='
], as_index=False).max()` and it seemed to work.

Comment: No my dataframe is actually a whole lot bigger, And there's a lot of merge based on different columns. 4 merges actually.
And after the 4 merges the result of the dataframe looks somewhat similar to the example I put in question. and there's more rows and columns than the truncated one I posted. in the actual dataframe

Comment: If you update your question with more information maybe I can help. As far as I can tell my answer works with the example you've provided, so there's not much else I can do without more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I have updated the input and output table shapes in the question.
Can you kindly check it now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240510/discussion-between-eric-and-zeshan-ahmed-nobin).